# logserver with kibana-logstash and elasticsearch

Tags: linux, networking, server

I am trying to set up a loggingserver on ubuntu that displays all its logs trough kibana.

My kibana dashboard is empty. I have been searching for days now and it still doesn't work. Any ideas please?

this is the message that is being displayed at the top:
"NO RESULTS there were no results because no indices were found that match your selected time span"

Thank you